How to use "I wish to have done it"?

I wish to have said "sorry" to her.

It means that know I wish that I did something differently in the past, correct?

I wish to have cleaned the room when she came

Does it mean I wanted to clean before or after "she came"/

Hi.  Sorry but your sentences aren't grammatical.  "I wish to have [done something]" is not a construct used in English.  It should be "I wish [that] I had [done something]".

People need to ask the questions and be corrected in answers. You should have done some research first, of course. Please do so next time.

"I wish to have said ..." is grammatical but stilted. It refers to  something you wish to have done, come some future point in time. It's not a regret but an explanation, perhaps of some action you're taking now to make the future apology possible.

@BillyKerr I agree. wish to have done is not grammatical in English.

marta, I have given you an answer. Why aren't  you responding to it?

OP: I wish to have said "sorry" to her.
Correction:
I wish I had said sorry to her.
OP: I wish to have cleaned the room when she came
Does it mean I wanted to clean before or after "she came"
Correction:
I wish I had cleaned the room when/before she came in or arrived.
wish with to:
Is like want: I want to clean the room. I wish to clean the room.
Another example: I want to leave now. I wish to leave now.
wish is followed by a past perfect OR would/could.

I wish I had done it. or I wish I had said it.

I wish you could/would come with me to Paris.
Or a past continuous:

I wish you were coming with me to Paris.


wish to do something or have something done is somewhat formal or old fashioned.

I wish to have cleaned my room  before my mom comes back from work. Correct or still wrong?

@thomas Not good. I wish to clean my room before she comes back from work. But in everyday speech, we'd say want there probably.

@thomas - It reminds me of those fairy tales where someone is granted three (magic) wishes, and they wish for the room to be clean without them having to do the work. You wouldn't say it in a real life situation.

@KateBunting is on to something here - we use "I wish" for things that are impossible or imaginary (or perhaps nearly impossible). That's why it's common in the past but not the future - the past cannot be changed but in the future things are still possible. For an idiomatic example in the future, we might say, "I wish I had the time to clean my room before she comes back," which strongly implies that you don't have the time at all so cleaning your room is not possible.

@CanadianYankee Sure, but time was not in the question. Sometimes just dealing with an actual question should be enough.
